# Stuck when creating credentials - Yargs through package.json is deprecated

Tags: express-gateway

I´m using Windows 10 and following the "Getting started" tutorial, but after creation of user I can´t create the credential for him.

the command line:

eg credentials create -c bob -t key-auth -q

the result:

Configuring yargs through package.json is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release, please use the JS API instead.
Configuring yargs through package.json is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release, please use the JS API instead.
Configuring yargs through package.json is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release, please use the JS API instead.

then I must press Control+C to stop the process.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

unfortunately yes, we have a problem with `yargs` on Windows which is actually tracked in our GitHub repository: https://github.com/ExpressGateway/express-gateway/issues/889

My idea would be to replace yargs with `oclif` or something modern, but I haven't been able to work on it yet.

Also, I do not have a Windows machine so it is kind of difficult to test it out properly.

Comment: Thansk for your answer! I´ll try to use the GitBash or PowerShell in order to generate the credentials!

Comment: I´ve used the gitBash and it worked. Another problem I´ve faced is that I can´t access the admin page, it return "Cannot GET /ip" when I try to access the localhost:9876 page:

`info: gateway http server listening on :::8080

info: admin http server listening on 127.0.0.1:9876`


`$ curl http://localhost:8080/ip

...
<title>Error</title>
...
<pre>Cannot GET /ip</pre>`

Comment: You might need to change the listening interface to 0.0.0.0 so that processes outside of the containers can talk with the admin API

Comment: I am facing the same issue.