# Configuring yargs through package.json and gitBash

Tags: express-gateway

I know that such a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56582373/stuck-when-creating-credentials-yargs-through-package-json-is-deprecated) has already been here, but using gitBash helped, so in my case it did not help, not using gitBash, PowerShell, maybe someone was able to fix the problem during this time?

Comment: In the referenced question, “works” means that the error was observed, not that it has been resolved. Express Gatewsy’s author no longer supports the package, so you would have to fork the project and fix the underlying problem yourself unless someone else has done so.

Comment: @James McLeod Thank you, is it worth using this package at all if it is no longer supported? is there a replacement for him?

Comment: I think only you can answer that for your use case. I found it absolutely invaluable to learn about API gateways and for rapid development on my local system but your mileage may vary.

Comment: @James McLeod thanks